# How to read from one object file without linking with other object file?

Tags: c

I have some binary data in text file:
file name: **bin_data:**
0x04
0x82
0x48
0x69

I have converted them into binary using 
**ld -r -b binary -o bin_data.o bin_data**

I have written one CPP program

file name: **check.cpp**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>


extern char _binary_bin_data_start[];
extern char _binary_bin_data_end[];
int main() 
{
    printf(" start \n");    
    printf( "address of start: %p\n", &_binary_bin_data_start);
    printf( "address of end: %p\n", &_binary_bin_data_end);
    for (char* p = _binary_bin_data_start; p != _binary_bin_data_end; ++p)
    {
     putchar( *p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have compiled the check.cpp & genratedcheck.o

in order to read the data from bin_data.o , I need to link both the file and generated **a.o** and ran.
In my application **bin_data**  will change for every simulation and I don't want to link check.o & bin_data.o every time there is change in bin_data.
is there any work around here?  so that I don't have to link check.o & bin_data.o

**Example:**

**simulation 1**

**bin_data** file : 0x04,0x82,0x48,0x69

```
ld -r -b binary -o bin_data.o bin_data   -> generates bin_data.o
gcc -c check.cpp                             -> generates check.o
gcc check.o bin_data.o
./a.out
```

**Output:**

```
0x04
0x82
0x48
0x69
```

**simulation 2**

change data in **bin_data** file : 0x55,0x66,0x77,0x88,0x99

```
ld -r -b binary -o bin_data.o bin_data   -> generates bin_data.o
//gcc -c check.cpp          //want to avoid this step
//gcc check.o bin_data.o    //want to avoid this step
./a.out
```

**Output:**

```
0x55
0x66
0x77
0x88
0x99
```

Comment: just don't embed the data in your executable and read it from the original text file directly?

Comment: Very unclear what you're trying to do ...

Comment: On  a side note: Remove `using namespace std;`.

Comment: The only standard way of doing it is to convert the file into `{ 0xaa, 0xbb, .... }` and declare a variable into your C file. If you ask about GNU ld linker and about linux, please describe your environment and add the relevant tags.  Nonetheless, if `bin_data` changes each time your program runs, then you have to read the `bin_data` each time your program runs, so read it using `fopen` and `fread`.... `one CPP program` cpp is C++ extension, not C.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do want to read the data as a file during the execution and do not want to make again the executable each time you modify the data, the only possibility seems to put the data in a *dynamic library*. Doing that you just have to redo the dynamic library each time you modify the data and start again your executable without having to build it. Of course the signature of `_binary_bin_data_start` and `_binary_bin_data_end` must not change and stay `char[]`

Comment: Yes.. I tried the dynamic linking.
I have generated the check.so (shared library) & whenever I changed the "bin_data" file contents I just do linking it with my "check.so" and it is working fine.
I have taken the reference from http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html